# How can I shorten this PHP if statement?

Tags: php, arrays, string, optimization, if-statement

I have an if statement, and I need to compare a single string with many different options. The code I post below shows what I mean pretty clear. I know 2 ways of doing this, but the other is even longer. So, is there any function that makes something like this, but in a shorter way? It might seem silly what I asked for, but I expect the list of subpages to grow really fast. This is the code:

```
if  (
    $Url[0]=="contact"||
    $Url[0]=="report"||
    $Url[0]=="new"
    )
    {
    //Do something
    }
```

And I'd like to know if there's something like this:

```
if ( weirdcomparefunction ($Url[0],"contact","report","new") )
    {
    //Do something
    }
```

The problem I see to create my own function is that the number of variables passed is (ironically) variable.

Or even something like this:

```
$centered = array ("contact","report","new");
if ( weirdcomparefunction ($Url[0],$centered) )
    {
    //Do something
    }
```

I'm also thinking about creating a .txt to store all the subpages with breaklines, but I'd need a big script so I'd like to know first if there is already a weirdcomparefunction(). Therefore it'd need to be SHORT, otherwise I'd have no problem making about 10-20 lines with some whiles and ifs.

Thank you all.

Comment: How about using a switch, having cases without a break?

Comment: The other answers were right, but this is also clever. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```
$centered = array ("contact","report","new");
if(in_array($Url[0], $centered)) {
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Perfect. The script had some extra details that I did not list (they weren't THAT important) that can also be implemented using this method. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You want [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).